# In Processing, getting constant stroke width independent of scale

Tags: processing

What value fed to strokeWidth() will give a stroke width of one pixel regardless of the current scale() setting?

Answer (score 2):

I think `strokeWeight(0)` should work. Here is an example:

```
void setup() {
   size(100,100);
   noFill();
   scale(10);
   // 1st square, stroke will be 10 pixels
   translate(3,3);
   strokeWeight(1);
   beginShape();
   vertex(-1.0, -1.0);
   vertex(-1.0,  1.0);
   vertex( 1.0,  1.0);
   vertex( 1.0, -1.0);
   endShape(CLOSE);
   // 2nd square, stroke will be 1 pixel
   translate(3,3);
   strokeWeight(0);
   beginShape();
   vertex(-1.0, -1.0);
   vertex(-1.0,  1.0);
   vertex( 1.0,  1.0);
   vertex( 1.0, -1.0);
   endShape(CLOSE);
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example of how `strokeWeight(0)` would be ignored by the scaling OP mentioned? A code snippet would be great if possible.

Comment: @Frits: Here is a code snippet:  `void setup() {
      size(100,100);
      scale(10);
      // 1st square, stroke will be 10 pixels
      translate(3,3);
      strokeWeight(1);
      beginShape();
      vertex(-1.0, -1.0);
      vertex(-1.0,  1.0);
      vertex( 1.0,  1.0);
      vertex( 1.0, -1.0);
      endShape(CLOSE);
      // 2nd square, stroke will be 1 pixel
      translate(3,3);
      strokeWeight(0);
      beginShape();
      vertex(-1.0, -1.0);
      vertex(-1.0,  1.0);
      vertex( 1.0,  1.0);
      vertex( 1.0, -1.0);
      endShape(CLOSE);
}`

Comment: That's great :D Please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45523575/edit) and add it in there instead of in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Kevin did offer a couple of good approaches. 
Your question doesn't make it clear what level of comfort you have with the language. My assumption (and I could be wrong) is that the layers approach isn't clear as you might have not used [PGraphics](http://processing.org/reference/PGraphics.html) before.

However, this option Kevin provided is simple and straight forward:

> multiplying the coordinates manually

Notice most drawing functions take not only the coordinates, but also dimensions ?
Don't use `scale()`, but keep track of a multiplier floating point variable that you use for the shape dimensions. Manually scale the dimensions of each shape:

```
void draw(){
  //map mouseX to a scale between 10% and 300%
  float scale = map(constrain(mouseX,0,width),0,width,0.1,3.0);

  background(255);
  //scale the shape dimensions, without using scale()
  ellipse(50,50, 30 * scale, 30 * scale);
}
```

You can run this as a demo bellow:

```js
function setup(){
  createCanvas(100,100);
}
function draw(){
  //map mouseX to a scale between 10% and 300%
  var scale = map(constrain(mouseX,0,width),0,width,0.1,3.0);
  
  background(200);
  //scale the shape dimensions, without using scale()
  ellipse(50,50, 30 * scale, 30 * scale);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.7/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Another answer is in the question itself: what value would you feed to `strokeWidth()` ? If `scale()` is making the stroke bigger, but you want to keep it's appearance the same, that means you need to use a smaller stroke weight as scale increases: the thickness is inversely proportional to the scale:

```
void draw(){
  //map mouseX to a scale between 10% and 300%
  float scale = map(constrain(mouseX,0,width),0,width,0.1,3.0);

  background(255);
  translate(50,50);
  scale(scale);
  strokeWeight(1/scale);
  //scaled shape, same appearing stroke, just smaller in value as scale increases
  ellipse(0,0, 30, 30);
}
```

You can run this bellow:

```js
function setup(){
  createCanvas(100,100);
}
function draw(){
  //map mouseX to a scale between 10% and 300%
  var scaleValue = map(constrain(mouseX,0,width),0,width,0.1,3.0);
  
  background(240);
  translate(50,50);
  scale(scaleValue);
  strokeWeight(1/scaleValue);
  //scale the shape dimensions, without using scale()
  ellipse(0,0, 30, 30);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.7/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Kevin was patient, not only to answer your question, but also your comments, being generous with his time. You need to be patient to carefully read and understand the answers provided. Try it on your own then come back with specific questions on clarifications if that's the case. It's the best way to learn.

Simply asking "how do I do this ?" without showing what you're tried and what your thinking behind the problem is, expecting a snippet to copy/paste will not get your very far and this is not what stackoverflow is about.

You'll have way more to gain by learning, using the available documentation and especially thinking about the problem on your own first. You might not crack the problem at the first go (I know I certainly don't), but reasoning about it and viewing it from different angles will get your gears going.

Always be patient, it will serve you well on the long run, regardless of the situation.

**Update** Perhaps you mean by

> What value fed to strokeWidth() will give a stroke width of one pixel regardless of the current scale() setting?

is how can you draw without [anti-aliasing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqi0114mwtY) ?

If so, you can disable smoothing via a line: calling [`noSmooth();`](https://processing.org/reference/noSmooth_.html) once in `setup()`. Try it with the example code above.

Comment: "Kevin did offer a couple of good approaches." I'm unclear what you mean by good. Neither answered the question. And thanks for your suggestions, but again, neither answers the question. When asked for a solution regardless of the current scale setting, "Don't use scale()" is less than useful - to put it mildly.

Comment: @ChrisJJ calm down: you're taking all this too seriously :) 
Frankly your one-liner question is a little vague and leaves a lot of room for interpretation: hence the many different options. If the core of the question is actually _one pixel thickness_ see my update above: just remove aliasing. Otherwise, please rephrase your question so it's as clear as possible. I'm surprised it hasn't been voted down yet, speaking of which, I don't believe you down voting Kevin and I is fair.

Answer (score -1):

None.

The whole point of `scale()` is that it, well, scales everything.

You might want to draw things in layers: draw one scaled layer, and one unscaled layer that contains the single-pixel-width lines. Then combine those layers.

That won't work if you need your layers to be mixed, such as an unscaled line on top of a scaled shape, on top of another scaled line. In that case you'll just have to unscale before drawing your lines, then scale again to draw your shapes.

Comment: "draw one scaled layer, and one unscaled layer that contains the single-pixel-width lines." Unfortunately that will fail to make the scaling of point positions of the single-pixel elements that I need. "That won't work if you need your layers to be mixed, such as an unscaled line on top of a scaled shape, on top of another scaled line. In that case you'll just have to unscale before drawing your lines, " Same problem.

Comment: @ChrisJJ I don't know what to tell you. What you've suggested isn't possible. You're going to have to come up with something else- maybe do the scaling yourself by multiplying the coordinates manually?